# can you handle the callback with timecode after playback completion or stopped by user?

Tags: actions-on-google

I would like to catch the hook "actions.intent.MEDIA_STATUS" with the timecode when the user stopped the playback streaming.

the status return by this callback is only when failed or finished (https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/Status)

https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#handling_callback_after_playback_completion

do you think that is possible to catch the timecode media ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reliable way to do this. As you note, the event sent does not contain the timecode where it stopped, or even the cause of why it stopped (did the user stop it or did it end). Other Intents may be triggered with the user requesting an action, and you won't even get the MEDIA_STATUS event.

You can get a very rough idea of where the user stopped by including the media start time in a context or in session data when you first send the reply. When you get the next message, you can compare the time that you previously saved with the current time. This is very imperfect, however, since it doesn't account for network latency or the user pausing and resuming the audio during playback.

Comment: Thanks you, i will do that.. An another question about the media response : It is possible to play a mp3 music at a specific time with '#' media fragment ?

Comment: If the answer has helped, upvoting and/or accepting it is always appreciated. If you have a different question, go ahead and ask it as a new question on StackOverflow.